# Can Google Sheet select a cell by it's color

Tags: google-sheets

I have applied the Conditional formatting to select a cell and color it

[image]

Considering the maroon cells, I currently just use the visual cue to copy paste the text in column C and then there are regex formulas to create the adapted code in cell D.

Instead of manually copying the text from A6 to C4 (in this case) is there a way to get the sheet to populate C4 with the first cell in A that has the maroon color (in this case A6)?

[Searches](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=google%20sheet%20select%20cell%20by%20color) only show results about filtering by color and not selecting by color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

*Use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and [getBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds).*

### Explanation

Open the script editor by clicking on Tools > Script Editor. It is based on JavaScript and allows you to create, access and modify Google Sheets files with a service called [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).

In this case, use the method `getBackgrounds` to get the color of any cell and then you can apply some logic. I attach you a simple snippet of code, where it displays the color of each cell in the range `A1:A10`

### Code

```
function testColor(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  const colors = ss.getRange('A1:A7').getBackgrounds()
  for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
    console.log(colors[i])
  }
}
```